# textBox Action Methods

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on a program that allows the user to enter a barcode via scanner and then do stuff, and I've got most of it worked out, I just can't figure out which action method for textBox1 would allow me to do something when "Enter" was hit while in the textBox. I've looked at the description of most of the actions, and I can't find one that sounds like it would work.

Is there one that would work? Or do I just have to check every time a key is pressed?

Comment: `Validate` events..or `KeyDown`

Comment: Whats wrong wiht OnKeyDown / OnKeyUp ?

Comment: It would trigger the event every time a number was entered into the box, no? Enter isn't being hit by the user, it's being entered by the scanner.

@DonBoitnott, Validated doesn't do quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: You can create an OnKeyUp event, then in the event just check the `KeyCode` that was hit.

Comment: Then perhaps you should dive deeper into explaining.  If enter isn't being 'pressed' by a user...then what is _really_ happening?  The scanner cannot press enter on the keyboard.

Comment: Keycodes are send by input devices, no matter if keyboard or scanner. The event is nothing about physically pressing any keys. How would the Mousekeyboard work then?
 Those scanners are usually configurable to send something like Enter after scanningseuqnece.

Comment: The scanner can imitate keys being pressed. It imitates the numbers of the barcode, and then the enter key afterwards. Thanks Gwin003, worked perfectly!

Comment: Barcode scanners do act as a virtual keyboard and send low level key strokes I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the KeyDown / OnKeyDown or KeyUp/OnKeyUp event, just filter for the right key:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyDown(e);

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

Or in your case since your parent form is most likely *subscribing* to the TextBox event then you would add a method like the following using the designer:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that what you are calling "Action Methods" are called Events.

Comment: Perfect, I wasn't aware you could get the keycode of a pressed key using that event. Thanks!! And I'll try to remember they're called Events, I'm still pretty new to C#.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using the KeyUp event:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            DoSomething();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try  handler the keypress event.
stop the handler and work better.

```
 using System;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Form1: Form
{
public Form1()
{
    // Create a TextBox control.
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    this.Controls.Add(tb);
    tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(keypressed);
}

private void keypressed(Object o, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // The keypressed method uses the KeyChar property to check  
    // whether the ENTER key is pressed.  

    // If the ENTER key is pressed, the Handled property is set to true,  
    // to indicate the event is handled. 
    if (e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

}